# Make new array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

A have some little problem with array in PHP.

I have this array:

[image: I have this array.]

There are many ['variants'] below.

I need to create a new array like this:

[image: new array like this]

from all ['variants'].

I have a function with this

```
$variants = array();
$features = $features['18']; foreach ($features as $feature) {
    if (!empty($feature['variants'])) {
        $variants = array_merge($variants, $feature['variants']);
    }
}
    fn_print_r($variants);
return $variants;
```

But it have error: `array_merge()` [function.array-merge]: Argument #2 is not an array.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please include your arrays inside your question. Also where do you have a key `18`? And what exactly is in `$features` before you loop over it?

Comment: $features['18'] - array like 1-st image

Comment: Your foreach loop does not make sense then, since you loop over each value and I don't see why you want to merge `variants`, since you only have it once in your array. Why not just do `$variants = $features["variants"];`?

Comment: If i do like this, i have array with old ["variants"] id. Like 197 - 198 ...  ect. I need new with id 0,1,2 ect.

Comment: Then just reindex the array with `array_values()`, e.g. `$variants = array_values($features["variants"]);`

Comment: thx a lot) It's work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you code correct - rewrite line 3:

```
if (!empty($feature['variants'])) {
```

on:

```
if (!empty($feature['variants']) && is_array($feature['variants'])) {
```

And I would give the call to **array_values**.
For example:

```
foreach($features as $feature)
{
    $result = [];
    if(isset($feature['variants']) && is_array($feature['variants']))
    {
        $result = array_merge($result, array_values($feature['variants']));
    }
}
```